# Build a specific Boost library using a makefile

Tags: c++, boost, makefile, build, linker

I am trying to include, the `boost::filesystem` library into a project. 
The project has to run on different architectures, so I don't want to link to the boost libraries installed on my ubuntu machine.

Most of boost is header only, so I would just have to include it and not worry about building it. But the filesystem library is NOT header only and I have to build the binaries for it.

Doing that would be easy, just pass in the header using the -I flag, and during the linking state, pass in the location to search for the binary using -L and specify the library using -l.

But I don't want to use the system headers and binaries.

So I am keeping a copy of the `boost::filesystem` headers within my project, using the `bcp` tool that boost provides.

I am able to do this, and I have a subdirectory `lib/fs/boost/filesystem`.

When I try to build a cpp file, dependent on filesystem, the compiler is able to find the headers and everything works.

But during the linking state. It cannot find the binary and the build fails.

So how do I build the `boost::filesystem` ?

1) I found the `bootstrap.sh` and `b2` way to do it. I am not sure how to use it with the bcp tool though. I was building the library from the boost root.

But a disadvantage this this approach, is that I am complicating things. Before running my makefile, I will have to run bootstrap and b2 to get the binaries. It doesn't seem clean and I would like to avoid this.

2) Is there a makefile rule that I can use to build the `boost::filesystem`. The project is build using a makefile, and if I could specify a rule to build the filesystem, and then link the resulting binaries, it would be great.

I searched online and I couldn't find a makefile to build a boost library. Can you point me at where I could find such a makefile ?

The question is verbose, but I am just doing it to make sure I am not making any wrong assumptions.

Thanks a lot.